# How can i use angular npm in a React ts project

Tags: reactjs, angular, npm, react-tsx, npm-package

my question is because where I work they asked me to carry out a project in react with TS and they ask me to integrate a library in npm built in angular, is it possible to do the integration or would I have to create my own library in react

Comment: why would you need it

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it is not possible. You'll have to find an alternative package made for React or make your own. Or find an alternative made for vanilla JS and make a React integration.